# Harddisk exchange from one MacBook Pro to another MacBook Pro with same configuration and model with different serial no

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, install

I am working as a system admin in a corporate company. Today I got one ticket from HR. HR is using MacBook Pro having a 100 GB harddisk. He needs to upgrade the harddisk from 100 to 500 GB. What I did at the moment is that I have the same MacBook Pro with 500 GB harddisk. I exchanged the harddisks for both the Mac in the live state that means on the state I didn't shut down both Macs.

After exchanging harddisks neither of the Mac boot. Is it possible to install new os for two Mac hard drives.

Comment: It should work, but you should never open a Mac while the system is on (I assume that is what you mean) there could be hardware damage to both systems.

Comment: I had to downvote this and would fire you immediately: 1. hot-swapping harddrives in MBPs 2. swapping the harddrives at all if the MBPs are really the same

Comment: Yoga... I say this genuinely, not to chastise you. Are you by chance a tier 1 help desk technician? Any true 'sysadmin' wouldn't know not to remove storage from a computer that's on.

We can help you, but we have incomplete information.

What model of MBP? Older ones, with 2.5" drives, or the newer ones with removable M.2-like PCIe flash storage? Remember that HDD != HD.

If indeed the HR computer is using a hard drive disk, id strongly recommend they cough up the ~$100 to install a solid state drive.

That said, hopefully you have a backup because you've made both drives unbootable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest putting both the harddisks back into the devices they were originally in and try booting again. Make sure the laptops are plugged in when you do this. If that doesn't work, it's very possible you've damaged the disks by trying to pull them out while the laptops were running.

If it does work, then I'd use time machine to create a backup of the 100GB disk you're replacing on an external USB drive. Then, after that's complete, power off the laptop, replace the disk with a new one, then [follow the steps here to "Restore from a Time Machine Backup"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314).

To be clear, this is assuming these are older MacBook Pro's with removable harddisks, not the solid-state drives that are soldered onto the motherboards. Those cannot be removed or replaced, at least not without permanently destroying the entire machine.

Comment: To add to this. It is best practice to fully back up a system before making changes to storage. Its quite possible you've cause irreparable damage to the system files. If the drives won't boot you can try reinstalling the OS. It may boot up fine after that. But you should absolutely recovery any important data first. Professional data recovery and can be quite expensive.